# Hosting my MVC 5 entity framework code first project ! MULTIPLE ERRORS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, hosting

I'm trying to host my ASP.NET MVC 5 Entity Framework code first project (the project is running perfectly fine on my machine with local db connection strings) on go daddy. I've been getting a few errors and I was able to correct them up until now.

Now I'm getting this error:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.     Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

I've removed the trust level option in my web.config file because it was creating problems with CAS trust level in the asp.net net parameters of godaddy. My CAS trust level in go daddy is set to full.

My connection strings:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=ipadress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-aspProjetFinal-20141211061340.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-aspProjetFinal-20141211061340;Integrated Security=false;User Id=myuser; Password=mypassword;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="monModel" 
     connectionString="data source=ipadress;initial catalog=GestionClientsContext;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;User Id=myuser; Password=mypassword;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I've tried a few things, for example, this:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1742970.aspx?CREATE+DATABASE+permission+denied+in+database+master+

But I'm not sure if I need to delete some lines after adding said line at the top of the code.

My `global.asax.cs` file:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<GestionClientsContext>(null);
        Database.SetInitializer(new InitialisationGestionClients());
        GestionClientsContext testing = new GestionClientsContext();
        testing.Database.Initialize(true);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        //throw new Exception(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    }
```

I clearly need some guidance, I've already spent a lot of hours just trying to get it online ! Let me know what you think ! Thanks !

Comment: Can you show us the `InitialisationGestionClients()` initializer? Are you using the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` scheme? If so, that may be the cause, since GoDaddy doesn't allow you to drop or create databases from the code, only the Control Panel.

Comment: Is your DB already exist?, Did you set connection string in your contact? or have admin user access to your DB in SQL?

Comment: My 2 DBs already exist, the one linked to the context and the one for the logins and roles. I've created them myself on the server.

Answer (score 0):

What you asked for Dan:

```
 public class InitialisationGestionClients : System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<GestionClientsContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(GestionClientsContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
        var lesClients = new List<Clients>
         {
             new Clients{nom="Finch", prenom="Paul",dateInscription=DateTime.Parse("2014-01-10"),adresse="911 De la Commune", email="test@hotmail.com", solde=0,commentaires="Juste un test"}
         };
        lesClients.ForEach(s => context.Clients.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var lesFacures = new List<Factures>
        {
            new Factures{motif="Programmes janvier 2014", montant=25,dateFacturation=DateTime.Parse("2014-01-10"),statusPaid=false, ClientsId=1}
        };

        lesFacures.ForEach(s => context.Factures.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var lesPaiements = new List<Paiements>
        {
            new Paiements{montant=25,datePaiements=DateTime.Parse("2014-02-10"), ClientsId=1}
        };
        lesPaiements.ForEach(s => context.Paiements.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();


    }

}
```

UPDATE: I've gotten the site to "run" if I can use this word. I can now access the application online BUT as soon as I try to login or create a new user, using the MVC login feature, I get the following error:

CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

I already got that error before when the application was trying to load but I didn't get it since I change the trust level to FULL. I'm not sure I'm following this one ! I'm just trying to login why is he trying to create anything at all !